# AfterClean Target Doesn't Get Invoked When I Clean The Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've added a 'BeforeClean' and an 'AfterClean' target to my .csproj file, originally designed to delete some build artifacts in locations outside the normal build path.

When I did a "clean" on the project, I could tell that the files weren't getting deleted; so I dumbed down the action to just spit a message out.  Like the delete command, the message command isn't getting invoked (I'm expecting to see the message in the 'Output' window).

The only relevant advice I could find on the web was to make sure that you do your target definitions *after* you import the Microsoft.CSharp.targets file.  I'm including the clip of my .csproj file with enough detail to show where my target defs are vis-a-vis the import.

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything right; why would my targets not get invoked?

Thanks in advance.

[Update and FYI:  I was able to get the Target to fire when changing Importance from 'normal' to 'high.']

```
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
        <PropertyGroup>
            <PreBuildEvent>
            </PreBuildEvent>
        </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="BeforeClean">
        <Message Text="Hello Clean World!" Importance="normal" ContinueOnError="true"/>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterClean">
        <Message Text="Goodbye Clean World!" Importance="normal" ContinueOnError="true"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually is getting invoked, you just can't see it.  Run msbuild.exe with /verbosity:normal.  Or change the IDE setting:  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.

Or change the Importance attribute to `high`.

Comment: actually does not seem to. this has the answer that work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206011/6196679

Answer (score 2):

`<Target Name="AfterClean">` *is* ignored in dotnet core with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`, and the problem isn't the verbosity. Instead, the `AfterTargets="Clean"` approach works:

```xml
    <Target Name="PrintGoodbye" AfterTargets="Clean">
      <Message Text="Goodbye Clean World!" Importance="normal" ContinueOnError="true"/>
    </Target>
```

run like:

```
$ dotnet clean 
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
Build started 12/9/2022 9:05:04 AM.
     1>Project "C:\code\dotNetBytes\Tests\Tests.csproj" on node 1 (Clean target(s)).
     1>PrintGoodbye:
         Goodbye Clean World!
     1>Done Building Project "C:\code\dotNetBytes\Tests\Tests.csproj" (Clean target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.82
```